Zoom on figure on hover: don't increase size of border surrounding it
I have the following figure with caption in my html:
<figure id="pub_img"><img src="images/{{image.link}}" >
    <figcaption>{{image.caption}}</figcaption>
    </figure>

The css code below does among other things the following:

Make sure figure and img adhere to the width and float to the right
Make a 1 px black border around the image and the caption
On hover, enlarge the entire figure-img-caption construct.

I have an issues that I can't get right:
The zoom also increases the 1px black border -- which becomes quite ugly. I'm not sure how to increase the figure, img, figcaption, without increasing the border given to them.
How would I go about this?


#pub_img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(4);
  -moz-transform: scale(4);
  -o-transform: scale(4);
  transform: scale(4);
}

#pub_img {
  border: 1px solid #555;
  float: right;
  width: 80px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

figure {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 80px;
}

figure img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

figure figcaption {
  border-top: 0.1px solid gray;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 0.2em;
  text-align: justify;
}
<figure id="pub_img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/600/300">
  <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum</figcaption>
</figure>




You can not apply scaling only to certain "parts" of the element you are scaling. And you can't apply the border to an outside element either - because that won't grow in size, when the image inside gets scaled. You can either try and specify the border-width as a fraction of a pixel, like border-width: .25px;, so that when scaled up by a factor of 4, it should be more or less one pixel again. (Might not look perfect, due to rounding issues.) [...]

[...] Or you would need to replace the scaling with an actual modification of the width and height of the image instead. But that doesn't have as good a performance as scaling does, plus you'd probably need to position something absolute, to not have the rest of the layout "jump."

@CBroe border-width: .25px won't do it. It makes no difference compared to 1px - here.

@iorgv if I understand correctly even more generally, there is no valid size < 1px if defined via px.

@FooBar It doesn't matter if we use a smaller value, it behaves the same as 1px. I also tried em as unit, but no avail, the upscaling didn't happen the way CBroe suggests. There's no .25px to begin with that will become 1px. I mean that the .25px is the same as 1px, no difference.

You can't use scaling for that. It's an analogue to the opacity property on transparency, (it needs to be rgba, otherwise it will affect the entire element). Here we need to increase the width of the figure and the font-size of the figcaption, not scale it, like so:


#pub_img:hover {
  width: 325.33px;
}

#pub_img:hover figcaption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#pub_img {
  border: 1px solid #555;
  float: right;
  width: 80px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

figure {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 80px;
}

figure img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

figure figcaption {
  border-top: 0.1px solid gray;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 0.2em;
  text-align: justify;
}
<figure id="pub_img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/600/300">
  <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum</figcaption>
</figure>



Alternative version where text zoom is delayed:


#pub_img:hover {
  width: 325.33px;
}

#pub_img:hover figcaption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#pub_img {
  border: 1px solid #555;
  float: right;
  width: 80px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

figure {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 80px;
}

figure img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

figcaption > div {
  overflow: hidden;
}



figure figcaption {
  border-top: 0.1px solid gray;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 0.2em;
  text-align: justify;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 0fr;
  transition: 250ms grid-template-rows ease;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

figure:hover figcaption {
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
<figure id="pub_img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/600/300">
  <figcaption><div>Lorem Ipsum</div></figcaption>
</figure>




This worked almost perfectly: I didn't like that the figure increase was almost smooth, but the text was instantaneously increased, leading to a temporary "pop" at the start where the text is large but the figure is not. I added a second code snippet into your response. Let me know if you don't like it and I will put that into a separate answer instead.

The edit is okay by me, no problem at all - thank you for it, and also thanks for accepting my answer.
